# Using latitude and longitude to find sunrise/sunset times via REST webservice

Tags: android, web-services

Firstly I've only been coding in Android/Java for a couple weeks so apologies if this is a simple question or if I don't understand your answer.

I'm trying to take the latitude and longitude data from the phone and then use this in the following sunrise/sunset webservice:
http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm

I have managed to set up a button display the latitude and longitude in a textview and I have set another button up to display the result of the webservice using a static url. Now I just need to combine the two.

How do I go about taking the latitude and longitude data and putting into the url of the webservive? (http://www.earthtools.org/sun/**LATITUDE/LONGITUDE**/28/03/99/0)

Here is how my code currently looks:

```
    package richgrundy.learnphotography;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class SunriseSunset extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public Button getLocation;
public TextView LongCoord;
public TextView LatCoord;
public double longitude;
public double latitude;
public LocationManager lm;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sunrisesunset);
    findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1,
            new MyLocationListener());

    getLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GetLocation);
    LongCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LongCoord);
    LatCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LatCoord);

    getLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            showCurrentLocation();
        }

    });

}

protected void showCurrentLocation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Location location = lm
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    LongCoord.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
    LatCoord.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    b.setClickable(false);
    new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}

private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity)
            throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        InputStream in = entity.getContent();
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
        int n = 1;
        while (n > 0) {
            byte[] b = new byte[4096];
            n = in.read(b);
            if (n > 0)
                out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
        }
        return out.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "http://www.earthtools.org/sun/52.77431872/-1.20639/28/03/99/0");
        String text = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,
                    localContext);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return text;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        if (results != null) {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
            et.setText(results);
        }
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        b.setClickable(true);
    }
}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
}
```

I tried using the following code but couldn't get that to work:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    String url = "http://www.earthtools.org/sun/" + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) + "/28/03/99/0";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
```

Any help would be massively appreciated as I've been stuck on this for a couple days now.

Thanks =)

Comment: you are trying to send the current location lat and long through url?

Comment: Yes, so the idea is that the current lat and long is sent through the url and the webservice then returns the sunrise and sunset data for the current location.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you month and date.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Now You can do like this :

```
String finalURL = "http://www.earthtools.org/sun/"+LatCoord.getText().toString().trim()+"/"+LongCoord.getText().toString().trim()+"/"+formattedDate+"/99/0";
```

Now pass this String to `HttpGet` like this:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(finalURL);
```

Comment: Ah that works perfectly, Thank you so much for your help!
I may be back later with another question about how I code it so the user can select a different instead of todays date and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just change "," to "/" in the url string. like this:

```
String url = "http://www.earthtools.org/sun/" + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + "/" + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) + "/28/03/99/0";
```

Because the call to the web service is LATITUDE/LONGITUDE/ not LATITUDE,LONGITUDE/

Comment: Ah well spotted but I'm still getting the following error message:
location cannot be resolved - in relation to location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude()

Comment: You can debug the call, just use Log.d("some-tag", url); to see which url you are calling, and maybe try it in a web browser. Then you will know if the call is OK, and which values you are passing, and you can look for your solution more easily.